# Convert 17GB JSON file to a numpy array

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, hadoop

I have a big 17 GB JSON file placed in hdfs . I need to read that file and convert into nummy array which is then passed into K-Means clustering algorithm. I tried many ways but system slows down and getting a memory error or kernel dies.

[image: JSON structure]

the code i tried is

```
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem
import pandas as pd
import numpy as nm
import json
hdfs = HDFileSystem(host='hostname', port=8020)
with hdfs.open('/user/iot_all_valid.json/') as f:
 for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataset= nm.array(df)
```

I tried using ijson but still not sure which is the right way to do this in faster way.

Comment: I mean. How. How. How do people even get 17GB JSON files? Isn't there some point when people stop and thing "hey, this is tabular data, several million rows of that, and I wonder whether a tabular data format might be better than this general structureless JSON mess"?

Comment: :( The data is coming from IOT sensor and it is stored in Hadoop.

Comment: yes, but no IoT sensor alone will send you a 17GB JSON file. Somewhere, you aggregated that data and decided to dump it in a single JSON file. And that was a mistake. If it's in Hadoop, I'm sure there's better export formats than JSON.

Comment: In fact, Hadoop **is** a data storage *and analysis* framework. You should probably just work directly with your hadoop instance to get the data you want instead of working with a dump of the database. (this feels very obvious, but I think it might still have been worth writing for future readers).

Answer (score 1):

Because the data types are all going to be different per column a pandas dataframe would be a more appropriate data structure to keep it in.  You can still manipulate the data with numpy functions.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_json('/user/iot_all_valid.json', dtype={<express converters for the different types here>})
```

In order to avoid the crashing issue, try running the k-means on a small sample on the data set.  Make sure that works like expected.  Then you can increase the data size till you feel comfortable with the whole data set.

Comment: Okay..Also I dont want all the elements in the Json only 4 elements for the algorithm. is there a way to pick up only those?

select "macAddress","value"."speed", "value"."trackId", "value"."trackPos", "value"."battery"
 where "deviceType"='AnkiCar' and "param"='status'

Comment: @MKN the sample image in your question doesn't contain those fields. It would be helpful if you included some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I would stay away from both numpy and Pandas, since you will get memory issues in both cases. I'd rather stick with [SFrame](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.html) or [the Blaze ecosystem](http://blaze.pydata.org/), which are designed specifically to handle this kind of "big data" cases. Amazing tools!

Comment: in your opinion, what do you think about partially loading data into panda data frames, for example lets say you have 100 million rows in a file and you want to use pandas, you have a partitioning key such that 100k rows are related to each key, in such a scenario, dont you think you can read 100k rows using one key, move to the next?

Answer (score 1):

In order to deal with a numpy array potentially larger than available ram I would use a [memory mapped numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).  On my machine ujson was 3.8 times faster than builtin json. Assuming rows is the number of lines of json:

```
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem
import numpy as nm
import ujson as json
rows=int(1e8)
columns=4
# 'w+' will overwrite any existing output.npy
out = np.memmap('output.npy', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(rows,columns))
with hdfs.open('/user/iot_all_valid.json/') as f:
    for row, line in enumerate(f):
        data = json.loads(line)
        # convert data to numerical array
        out[row] = data
out.flush()
# memmap closes on delete.
del out
```